# What is correct usage of 'non-synchronous'?

Tags: adjectives

I am writing a paragraph on "Learning and teaching dispositions". I am sort of confused about the usage of an adjective: non-synchronous.

What will be the opposite of:
Synchronized (learning and teaching) dispositions.

I have written this way:
Non-synchronous (learning and teaching) dispositions.

Is the usage of "non-synchronous" right?

Comment: I'll assume you are referring to "Synchronized (learning and teaching) dispositions", and not "(Synchronized learning) and (teaching dispositions)". The 'thing' you want to find an antonym for is then "synchronized dispositions". The natural antonym is "unsynchronized dispositions", but you haven't given enough detail for this to be conclusive. "Non-synchronous" refers to doing things at different times. "Unsynchronized" can have a similar literal meaning, but also has a figurative sense along the lines that the things are 'mismatched'.

Comment: @ Lawrence , Thanks Lawrence, You have really explained the difference in detail. I am talking about "Synchronised (learning and teaching) dispositions". Could you mention the source of an adjective "unsynchronized", please?

Comment: Are you sure that **Synchronised** is a good adjective to use with dispositions. Synchronised refers to events happening at the same time. I can see that we could work to make some sequence of events be synchronised, But **dispositions** are not time related, they (if I understand the Educational usage correctly) are about attitudes.  We might want teacher and student to share common or complementary dispositions, but can they synchronise them?

Comment: I am not sure you are using a correct adjective as @djna memtioned, but the opposite is "asynchronous"

Comment: @djna and Cardinal, it is said, there is always a room for improvement. Please correct me if am wrong, it will be a great opportunity to learn from both of you. I think "synchronized" can be used for teaching and learning dispositions.By dispositions I certainly mean "attitudes". By "synchronized (learning and teaching )dispositions" , I mean learning and teaching attitudes which are synchronized. Well, if you want to read a paragraph in which I have used this term, I can present that too.

Comment: @Amn Yes, please present a paragraph using your term. It would also be helpful for you to give an example that uses the antonym. I assume you mean the case where teacher and student have 'different' attitudes towards learning - but in what way? ([Edit] those paragraphs / examples into your question.) About your request for a source for *unsynchronized* as an adjective, I'm not sure what you're looking for - do you mean a dictionary entry, etymology, or something else?

Comment: Synchronous- and asynchronous-learning/teaching have come to have specific meanings in education. Specifically, *asynchronous* teaching and learning most often refers to education where the student and teacher don't have to participate at the same time (like pre-recorded online lectures and old-fashioned correspondence courses). *Synchronous*, in contrast, would include traditional face-to-face teaching and also things like live-chat in an online course. See http://edglossary.org/asynchronous-learning/ Is that what you mean?

Comment: The poster has clarified that he is talking about attitudes (dispositions): **I mean learning and teaching attitudes which are synchronized**. Now that we understant from, @1006a that synchronous and asynchronous learning are very specific terms in education I am even more convinced that that the use of synchronous is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @ Lawrence Yes, I was asking for the dictionary entry.

Comment: @1006a Thank you very much. I appreciate the way you have given me the right direction about the correct usage of adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two similar words: **Synchronous** and **Synchronized**. Both are derived from the Greek Chronos and relate to time.

**Synchronized** is used for activities where time must match exactly. We synchronize our watches, synchronized swimming requires that swimmers exactly match each other's movements.

One dictionary definition: **to cause to go on, move, operate, work, etc., at the same rate and exactly together**

**Synchronous** has a similar implication but usually refers to a single event.

Definition **occurring at the same time; coinciding in time; contemporaneous; simultaneous.**

There is a specialised usage in IT: when two computers are interacting they may do synchronously or asynchronously. Synchronously implies that one computer will send a message and **wait** for a response from the second computer before doing further work. In asynchronous processing the first computer will send a request and expect an answer some time in the future, meanwhile it will continue with other tasks.

As @1006a has said, education terminology makes similar use of synchronous and asynchronous; depending upon whether the teacher and student interact directly.

You are speaking about dispositions and attitudes, which are not time-related. Hence I advise you not to use the terms synchronous or synchronised. I think the concept you are trying to express is that education is facilitated when the teacher's disposition and the student's disposition are aligned. We do not require that teacher and student have the **same** disposition, but that the dispositions are in some way complementary. As a trivial example: the teacher wants to teach, and the student wants to learn. More deeply: the teacher has a disposition for dialogue and the student a disposition to use such dialogue constructively.

My recommendation: use term such **complementary** and **conflicting** or **harmonious** and **discordant**.

Comment: Kindly read the paragraphs in which I have used these terms. 1) ....... On me, my parents imposed their wish: "You must become a doctor, NO MATTER WHAT!". Notwithstanding lack of interest, I joined the Science group. Being a dedicated student, I worked very hard to come up to my parents' expectations but all my good intentions turned into catastrophes. Alas! learning and teaching dispositions in my classroom were not synchronized. My teacher would always demand "cramming" whereas, I had entirely a different learning disposition........

Comment: 2) .......I didn't for a moment feel as an alien in my new classroom. It was an emotionally safe, stress free, flexible, justified and learning-centred classroom. My class teacher was very considerate and democratic. Luckily, I found synchronized learning and teaching dispositions. My teacher and I were on the same grid. As a result, I managed to score third position in the final exams........

Comment: @ djna Yes, the word " aligned " is what I should have used in my paragraph writing. Thank you for your efforts. Also, please mention what will be the antonym of "aligned (learning and teaching) dispositions".

Comment: Literally, misaligned. I might prefer conflicting.